# Web scraping com Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, xml, aplicação-web, scraping

Quero fazer um web scraping que lê uma página XML e pega determinado valor que está no "name", mas, não sei exatamente se é possível - só encontrei em como fazer com NodeJS -, é possível fazer com JS puro? Sem bibliotecas externas e/ou frameworks?

Answer (score 3):

Não há nada que te impeça de fazer o download de um XML e analisar o seu conteúdo. O único problema de fazer isso em um browser seria a [política de mesma origem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADtica_de_mesma_origem), que te impediria de acessar endereços arbitrários via Javascript.

Comment: Será para um script de addon, quando entender melhor, vou tentar e se não funcionar, faço gambiarras, é trabalho interdisciplinar, acho que não vai se aplicar.

Comment: Quais exatamente são os requisitos?

Comment: Minha ideia para o addon `e que leia as datas e titulos das postagens, que estao neste site: http://feed43.com/ufs.xml e, se tiver alguma na data que o usuario vai selecionar, mostre o titulo e o link.

Comment: É... Não existem formas seguras ou que não envolvam criar um servidor proxy pra fazer o que você quer fazer em um navegador. Acho que é hora de mudar de planos. :(

Comment: @PabloAlmeida As extensões não estão limitadas à política de mesma origem https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr

Answer (score 3):

É possível sim. Por exemplo:

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var tmplXML = document.getElementById("tmplXML");
var blobXML = new Blob([tmplXML.innerHTML], { type: 'text/xml' });
var urlXML = URL.createObjectURL(blobXML);

var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

httpRequest.open("GET", urlXML, true);
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4){
    if (httpRequest.status == 200) { 
      var xml = httpRequest.responseXML;
      console.log(xml.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
httpRequest.send();
```

```html
<template id="tmplXML">
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <text>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Nihil cumque vero</p>
    <p>Impedit quibusdam fuga</p>
    <p>Magnam ad maiores omnis</p>
    <p>Aliqua omnis laborum</p>
  </text>
</template>
```

Porém como o colega Pablo já falou, pode ser que a política de mesma origem dificulte o seu trabalho.

Fonte: [Ajax lendo XML](http://wbruno.com.br/ajax/exemplo-ajax-lendo-arquivo-xml/)

Comment: ótimo exemplo, porem tomei liberdade de juntar os seus dois snippets, assim como passei a criar um XML em memoria para que a sua requisição AJAX não retorna-se um erro.

Comment: Vou comecar a estudar esses metodos, se conseguir, finalizo o post ainda hoje. +D